# jQuery のアコーディオンに、それぞれのコンテンツ縦幅を設定したいです

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, jquery-ui

アコーディオンを使ったウェブページをつくっておりまして、そのアコーディオン自体は正常に動いております。（動作は問題ないです）

アコーディオンは５つありまして、その一つ一つにそれぞれのコンテンツをいれたサイトを作りたいのですが、たとえばAのコンテンツを開くと縦幅が長すぎて、下のほうに空欄が出てしまいます。（B,C、D、Eも同様です）。

JavaScript で CSS の命令文を書き込まなければいけないんだろうなぁ・・・って言うのはうすうすわかっているつもりですが、いかんせん、いかに書くのかがわかりません。
↓こんな感じで。

```
<script>
？？？？？？？？？？？
</script>
```

以下は、現状僕が作っているサイトの header と body の一部です。

教えてください。よろしくお願いいたします。

```html
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({ collapsible: true
    });
  });
  </script>


<body>
 <div id="accordion">

              <div id="A_btn">Aボタン</div>
              <div id="a-contents">
                  Aのコンテンツがいろいろ入っています。
　　　　　　　　　　画像もあれこれ
　　　　　　　　　　１００pxもあれば十分です。
              </div>


               <div id="B_btn">Bボタン</div>

                <div id="b-contents>
                    Bのコンテンツがいっぱい入っています。
   　　　　　　　　　このコンテンツは縦幅が長く、300pxはほしいです。  
                 </div>


                 <div id="c_btn">Cボタン</div>
                          <div id="C-contents">
                            Cのコンテンツは決まっていません

                          </div>


                      <div id="D_btn">Dボタン</div> 
                          <div id="d-contents">
                         Dのコンテンツもまだです。
                          </div>

                       <div id="E_btn">Eボタン</div>
                          <div id="e-contents">
                          <p>製作中です。しばらくお待ちください。</p>
                          </div>


       </div><!--end accordion-->
```

Comment: 今回もご協力いただき、ありがとうございます！

おかげさまで前進できました。
前進した先に壁があると思いますが、また、ぜひとも相談させてください

Comment: 解決したら、一番役に立った回答 (この質問の場合一つなのでもう決まっていますが) の左にあるチェックマークをクリックしておくと、質問を解決済みにでき、ステータスが分かりやすくなります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

デフォルトではそれぞれのコンテンツの高さは最も高い要素の高さに合わせられます。
`heightStyle: "content"`を指定してください。

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({collapsible: true, heightStyle: "content" });
});
```

[Accordion - No auto height | jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#no-auto-height)

そのあと各要素の高さを指定すれば良いです。`height()`を使ってください。

```
$("#a-contents").height(100);
$("#b-contents").height(300);
```

単位を指定しなければデフォルトでpx指定となります。

Comment: 些細なことですが、基礎から教えていただきありがとうございます！

ということは、script内にjavascriptのプログラムをすればcssも可能ということですよね？！

なんだか、ちょっと道がひらけてきました


また、よろしくお願いいたします

Comment: jQueryでCSSの設定は何でも動的にできますよ。`$("#e-contents").find("p").css({"color":"#ffffff","background-color":"#006600"})`とか。

Comment: 気がつかずにお返事が遅れて申し訳ないです！

ありがとうございます！
やってみましたが、問題なく起動しました！
ほんと、勉強になります。すごいです・・・（そして自分がだめだときづく。。。）